# Angular2 Http get request with service

Tags: angular

I can't use my function (in a service) for an http get request but if I use my function in my component directly, it works.
I use a PHP file that returns return a JSON.

I receive this error

```
"Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
at assignAll (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:112997:29)
at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:113068:16)
at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6624:16)
at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6686:16)
at new ViewWrappedError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:63377:16)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:90236:23)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:90209:18)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:64323:20)
at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:74734:42)
at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25777:16)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25744:26)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25680:58
at Array.forEach (native)
at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25680:29)
at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25654:14)"
```

**It doesn't work**

Component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Shoe} from './shoe';
import {FileService} from  './../services/file.service';
import {ShoeService} from  './../services/shoe.service';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
    selector: 'shoe',
    templateUrl: 'shoe-detail.component.html',
    providers: [FileService]
})
export class ShoeDetailComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private shoeService: ShoeService) {}

data : any;

ngOnInit() {
        this.data = this.shoeService.getData();
    });
}
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Shoe } from './../shoe/shoe';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ShoeService {

constructor (private http: Http) {}

getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://.../test.php')
        .subscribe(data => data.json());
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$data = array(
    array('id' => '1','first_name' => 'Cynthia'),
    array('id' => '2','first_name' => 'Keith'),
    array('id' => '3','first_name' => 'Robert'),
    array('id' => '4','first_name' => 'Theresa'),
    array('id' => '5','first_name' => 'Margaret')
);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**It works**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Shoe} from './shoe';
import {FileService} from  './../services/file.service';
import {ShoeService} from  './../services/shoe.service';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'shoe',
    templateUrl: 'shoe-detail.component.html',
    providers: [FileService]
})
export class ShoeDetailComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private fileService: FileService,
            private shoeService: ShoeService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private http: Http) {
}

data: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://...test.php')
            .subscribe(data => this.data = data.json());
    });
}
}
```

Comment: are you providing the ShoeService?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your component you are calling the service which returns an Observable but you assign that Observable directly to your data instead of subscribing to its results.

It should be

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.shoeService.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
});
```

And in your service you should call map instead of subscribe so you return the data and not the HttpResult.

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://.../test.php')
        .map(data => data.json());
    }
}
```

Note that in order to provide better type support you should define what it is your methods return. Example: `getData(): Observable<any>` and even better would be if you replace `any` with an interface type you define or collection/array of interface if it is a collection.

Example

```
export interface IUser {id: number; first_name: string}
```

Service method

```
getData(): Observable<IUser[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://.../test.php')
        .Map(data => data.json() as IUser[]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should map to data using a response object as below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
@Injectable()

export class ShoeService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }
    getData(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this._http.get('http://......')
            .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log("data we got is " + JSON.stringify(data)))
                .catch(this.handleError);

    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Internal Server error');
    }
}
```

and your ngOnInit should be as

```
ngOnInit() : void{
        this._taskService.getData()
                    .subscribe(data => this.data = data,
                    error =>this.errorMessage =<any> error)
    }
```

Also, modify the type of your data in your ShoeDetailComponent as

```
data : any[]
```